# Identity column not incremented by 1?

Tags: sql-server

I've created 4 tables:

```
`Patient` (Id, Name, ..)

`Donor` (Id, Name, ..)

`BloodBank` (Id, Name, ..)

BloodBankDonors(DonorId, BloodBankId, ..)
```

And set the Id columns to Identity incremented by 1, seed 1. and made a relationship between (Donor, BloodBank) and (BloodBankDonors).
The problem is when I entered some data in the tables BloodBank and the patient, the auto generated Id column was: 1,3,4 and 1,4,5,8 respectively?!

Comment: Can you show the definition of your tables?

Comment: How can I get this definition?

Comment: If you *care* about the numerical values of identity columns, you're misusing them. You should treat them as opaque blobs that just happen to fit in numerically typed columns.

Comment: If you delete the records from your table the identity column will not re-use the ID i hope you have not deleted any records from the table.

Answer (score 2):

So many things can cause gaps in an IDENTITY column. For example rollbacks not resetting IDENTITY, deletes, etc.

So, why do you care about gaps? You shouldn't. If you need a contiguous sequence of numbers, stop using IDENTITY.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting data from table holds the log info holding ID (auto generated columns) for recovery purpose.

Try to truncate table and re-enter the data

```
truncate table Patient
```

May this help

Comment: DBCC CHECKIDENT('databasename.dbo.tablename', RESEED, number)

Comment: DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)

Comment: Use reset to make Identity start from 1

Answer (score 0):

You might deleting  (DELETE command) some records from tables "BloodBank" and the "patient".Deleting record from table holds the log info of column ID(auto generated column) for recovery Purpose. Instead use below mentioned code snippet after "DELETE" command:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('databasename.dbo.tablename', RESEED, number)
if number=0 then in the next insert the auto increment field will contain value 1

if number=101 then in the next insert the auto increment field will contain value 102.
```

for more clear answer, please share sql script which you are using to create tables and insert records.